# CSS - image to background color

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve an effect like below with CSS.  The blue circle represents and image.  The red is simply a background color, but will have different text depending on changes in the DOM.  I'm pretty sure I could figure out how to do this using absolute positioning, but I would really like to avoid that if at all possible. Is there another way I could achieve this with CSS?

[image: icon transitions to background color]

I'm sure it doesn't help that I can't really figure out how to refer to it properly in searches to get a relevant answer.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should prepare jsFiddle with `position: absolute` solution to make potential answers attempts easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdmW3/2/

I didn't use `position:absolute` in this example. You can remove the unnecessary CSS prefixes (-moz, -webkit)

HTML:

```
<div class="wow">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <span>World</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wow {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #D01528;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.wow > div {
    border: 1px solid #384B86;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 35px 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: I would say you nailed it. Kudos

Comment: Thanks!  Worked great!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say

- use a pseudo-element for the circle, rather than a real element (if possible with your markup).
- use border-radius 50% instead of a definite value.
- use a negative margin to push the circle half out of the rectangle.

Here's a Pen: http://codepen.io/davidtheclark/pen/anFmw

Comment: Hi davidtheclark, I ended up starting with your answer but was having issues because I needed to move the image in a bit to line up with some other elements on the page. It was very helpful, but the other answer ended up being the final solution for me.  Thanks you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to have text in both the circle and the background, you have two options:

A. floats
B. absolute positioning.

Absolute position isn't all that bad. I'll use inline style to illustrate:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">Circle Text</div>
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:100px;">Text</div>
</div>
```

But if you only need the text on the right, and the circle is Just an image, then you could use a transparent PNG/GIF, and use the first attribute to specify a default background color:

```
<div style="background: red url(circle-image.gif) no-repeat 0 0;padding-left:100px;">
Text
</div>
```

Simple as that!

Comment: Schien the first answer solved it for me.  the reason I was trying to avoid absolute positioning is that I am already working in an absolutely positioned element and I find that nesting these becomes complicated quickly.  Thank you for your input!

Comment: You're welcome. An absolutely positioned element itself serves as an anchoring container; all its children use its top left corner as their origin (0,0). Not sure if this explanation simplifies the mental model for a similar task next time. The ">" selector may not work in all browsers, so if compatibility is a concern, you know you have options.